# How to pass the filename to a .pipe() call using Gulp 4

Tags: gulp

I have a typical pipeline looking like this:

```js
gulp.src(somePaths, {base: "./"})
   .pipe(somePlugin({
      cwd: "some/path/that/should/depend/on/the/filename",
   })
   .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
```

How can I pass the name of the file being processed into that first `pipe()` call, so that I can provide an accurate path to the `cwd` parameter?

My usecase here is that `somePaths` contains the paths to several applications, and I need my plugin to know in which folder it should `cd` in order to build each one.

Comment: I would try two things first: 1) look in the documentation of `somePlugin` if there is a way to use the file name out of the box. 2) Parameterize the whole pipeline so it can be run once per each application.

Comment: @GOTO0 It doesn’t look like there is this possibility in gulp-elm, which is the plugin I’m using. But parameterizing the whole pipeline might be a great idea, since it also might help with not rebuilding all apps when just one of them changes. I’m also starting to look into `gulp-tap` that should be able to help me too.

Comment: @GOTO0 I now have a much nicer gulp task, thanks to your advice! I ended up not using gulp-tap and just parameterizing the function so that it works on a single application, and I can also rebuild only the relevant application when a file was changed.

Comment: Sounds great! I'm happy to hear that I could help.